# Bessel function identity fails to simplify, but only sometimes

Tags: simplifying-expressions

For Bessel functions of positive integer order, it is known that
$(J_{i-1}(\alpha_{i,n}))^2 = (J_{i+1}(\alpha_{i,n}))^2$ where $\alpha_{i,n}$ is the $n$th zero of $J_{i}(r)$. Indeed, Mathematica knows this as well

```
In[1]:= BesselJ[0, BesselJZero[1, 1]]^2 == BesselJ[2, BesselJZero[1, 1]]^2 // FullSimplify
Out[1]= True
```

However, if one tries the ratio instead, you get

```
In[2]:= BesselJ[0, BesselJZero[1, 1]]^2/BesselJ[2, BesselJZero[1, 1]]^2 // FullSimplify
Out[2]= BesselJ[0, BesselJZero[1, 1]]^2/BesselJ[2, BesselJZero[1, 1]]^2

In[3]:= BesselJ[0, BesselJZero[1, 1]]^2/BesselJ[2, BesselJZero[1, 1]]^2 == 1 // FullSimplify
Out[3]= True
```

As you can see it fails to simplify the ratio expression yet knows that the ratio is identical to $1$! Furthermore, it can still correctly simplify the boolean form of the expression.

Is there a particular reason why Mathematica refuses to simplify the expression but is fine at simplifying the boolean version?

Comment: Just a guess, but I recall reading somewhere that when dealing with expressions involving exact integers, Mathematica may use high precision numerical methods. It's possible that for the boolean cases, these methods are employed to determine equality, but not so in the ratio case. I.e. for the boolean case, you can move everything to one side and test for the expression evaluating to a specific value, zero.

Comment: `BesselJ[0, BesselJZero[1, 1]]^2/BesselJ[2, BesselJZero[1, 1]]^2 // 
  N[#, 50] & // RootApproximant`